# node.js multer rename uploaded file

Tags: node.js, multer

I am trying to rename an image file uploaded with multer by the request parameters.

Here is my code:

```
router.route('/upload/:userid')
.post(multer({
    dest: 'uploads/'
    }), function(req,res){
            fs.readFile('uploads/' + req.files.file.name, function(err, data) {
                fs.writeFile('uploads/' + req.params.userid + '.' + req.files.file.extension, data, function(err) {
                    fs.unlink('uploads/' + req.files.file.name, function(){
                        if(err) throw err;
                    });
                }); 
            });
            res.json({ message: 'Successfully uploaded image!' });
});
```

It works great but I was wondering if it exists something cleaner and easier with multer rename function.

It already tried something like this:

```
router.route('/upload/:userid')
.post(multer({
    dest: 'uploads/',
    rename: function(req,res) {
        return req.params.userid
    }
    }), function(req,res){
            res.json({ message: 'Successfully uploaded image!' });
});
```

But it does not work because req is not populated yet (undefined).

I use httpie to test my code with the following command:

```
http.exe -f POST http://localhost:8080/upload/171284 file@D:\....\cat.jpg
```

Is it possible to use rename function of multer to do what I do with fs?
Or is there a better way?

Thank you for your feedbacks.

Thomas

**EDIT**

My new code using diskStorage:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/')
  },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, req.params.userid + '-')
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

router.route('/upload/:userid')
    .post(multer({
        storage: storage
    }), function(req,res){
        res.json({ message: 'Successfully uploaded image!' });
});
```

That throws an error:

```
Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Object]
```

Answer (score 3):

Ther is no `rename` in Multer constructor, insted of that, there is a `filename` in [DiskStorage](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage).

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

> `filename` is used to determine what the file should be named inside
>   the folder. If no `filename` is given, each file will be given a
>   random name that doesn't include any file extension.

Comment: Thank you @Festo. But how can I put it into my router.route .post? I had to update to latest version of multer for using diskStorage and now my code above is not correct anymore..

Comment: @Thomi It is hard to say what the problem is without your updated code.