# Problem renaming image on server end following image upload

Tags: react-native, file-upload, multer, file-rename

I have the following code, in React Native...which uploads an image to a remote server.  The server uses a Node.js backend and Multer is used to handle the image upload:

```js
export default class Images extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      photo: null,
      user: 'Mr Smith'
    };
  }

...

  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('sender', this.state.user)
  data.append('picture', {uri: this.state.photo.uri, name: this.state.photo.name, type: this.state.photo.type })

//****UPLOAD TO SERVER

fetch(`https://myserver.com/_remote_images`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Accept': "application/json",
  },
  body: data,
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response) => {

    if (response.answer) {
      alert('Upload success!');
    } else {
      alert('Upload failed...response.answer' + response.answer);
    }  //response.answer (true) ...OR NOT 

  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Upload error in FETCH call to server: ', error);
    alert('Upload failed...(call to server)');
  });

//****

...

}  //class Images
```

The code posted above is functional.  Using it I am able to upload an image from the mobile device to the remote server.  As can be seen, I 'appended' a name for the 'sender' of the image.  My intention is to use this in the naming of the received file on the server end.  This is the problem I am having.  I am at a loss to figure how to use this name passed with the image when the server receives it.  Here is the code at the server end, using Multer to process the upload:

```js
    //File Uploads
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log("file.mimetype are: " + file.mimetype);
    console.log("file.fieldname are: " + file.fieldname);
    console.log("file.originalname are: " + file.originalname);

    cb(null, './uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + session.subscriber + '-' + file.originalname)
  }
});

// Init upload
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/)) {
      // upload only png and jpg format
      return cb(new Error('Please upload a Image'))
    }
    cb(undefined, true)
  },
  limits: {
    fileSize: 5000000  //5MB file size limit
  }
})

//****

app.post('/_remote_images', upload.single('picture'), uploadFiles);

function uploadFiles(req, res) {

  console.log(req.body);
  console.log("SENDER OF FILE: " + req.body.sender);
  console.log("REQUEST FILES: " + req.files);

  res.send({ answer: true })

}
```

As can be seen in the code above, the name assigned to the uploaded image is constructed inclusive of a 'session.subscriber'.  What I would like is to use the 'sender' passed along with the image to be assigned to 'session.subscriber'.  So in this example I have given the uploaded image should be renamed on the server end including "Mr Smith" in the name.

I thought at first to add that routine into the 'fileFilter'...however I had no luck there.  If somebody knows a way to use the passed 'sender name' information to rename the file on the server side I would be most appreciative.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js multer rename uploaded file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345298/node-js-multer-rename-uploaded-file)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no actually.  Then answer in that link you gave mentions using 'Filename'.  As you can see in my code, I am already using 'Filename' to rename the uploaded image.  My question is how to use information passed in the uploaded file to rename...since the 'upload' and other Multer functions seem to be executed before I can make usage of that passed information.